# Check if array of objects contains a specific value with specific property name

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, datatables

I have a table which  has checkbox options for each/individual row and "check all" option to select all the rows on current page.

They look like following:

```
  $(".chkAll").click(function () {//check and uncheck all function
            if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                table.rows().select(this.checked);
                var rowcollection = table.$("input:checkbox[class=checkItem]", { "page": "all" });
                rowcollection.each(function (index, elem) {
                   //$row.find('td:eq(2)').find('a:eq(0)').text($('.inputedTitle').val());
                    _SingleScannedItemIds.push(
                        {
                            "title": $(elem).attr("ebaytitle"),
                            "price": $(elem).attr("ebayprice"),
                            "itemid": $(elem).attr("ebayitemid"),

                        });
                    $(elem).prop("checked", true);
                    console.log(_SingleScannedItemIds);
                });
            }
            else {
                table.rows().deselect(this.checked);
                _SingleScannedItemIds = [];
                $('input:checkbox').removeAttr('checked');

            }
        });
```

Where _SingleScannedItemIds is defined as following:

```
_SingleScannedItemIds = [];
```

Now I have a datatable where I wanna check if this array of objects contains this specific element when the row gets rendered:

```
 "columns": [

                {

                "sWidth": "1%",
                "data": "ItemID",
                "name": "Checkbox",
                    "render": function (data, type, row) {
                     console.log(contains(_SingleScannedItemIds,"itemid"));
                    if (_SingleScannedItemIds.some(item => item.itemid=== row.itemid)) {
                            return 'checked';

                        }
                        return 'not checked';
                        console.log("not checked");
                    },
              "autoWidth": true
            }]
```

So the rendered td has a property called "itemid" and my array of objects also contains "itemid" property..

Now I just need to match if it really does contains it for the rendered TD... If it does, I'd simply like to write it out in console like console.log("has") or whatever?

I have tried using "some" method in javascript and the following one:

```
function contains(a, obj) {
        for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            if (JSON.stringify(a[i]) === JSON.stringify(obj)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

But none worked... What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: anyone guys ?  =)

Comment: you need to provide more details on this. What all libraries are being used and what exactly are you trying to achieve. You have written a long question but it's not making sense at all. I'd suggest you create a jsfiddle and share so we can understand your question.

Comment: @Maverick Im using only jQuery... I'm simply trying to check if array of objects contains some value under property called "itemid" and that's all ^^

Comment: `some` method should work...what is `row` parameter in render function? I think problem can be with it.

Comment: I don't really understand why have you written "console.log(contains(_SingleScannedItemIds,"itemid"));", esp the "itemid" part ? shouldn't you having an object here. Could you write console.log(JSON.stringify(obj)) inside "contains" and tell us what it outputs.

Comment: Can you add your HTML to create a working snippet?

Comment: See if [jQuery DataTables Checkboxes](https://www.gyrocode.com/projects/jquery-datatables-checkboxes/) could be helpful for you.